# How to set file's default suffix in webpack-dev-server?

Tags: webpack-dev-server

I use webpack-dev-server to server my project.Here is the question, When the browser send a request like **http://localhost:9000/test/menuList**,  acutally I want it to find **http://localhost:9000/test/menuList.json**. How should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try tweaking Webpack-dev-server proxy object **pathRewrite** property

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: <Your-Value>,
    proxy = {
        '/test/menuList': {
            target: http://localhost:9000/test/menuList,
            pathRewrite(req, options) {
                    return req + '.json';
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```